# I can't run built Visual Basic applications with resources in them?

Tags: vb.net

For whatever reason, I cannot run my Visual Basic applications that have resources in them. The only way I have gotten them launch is by doing it via Visual Studio.
If you don't understand yet:
There are two Visual Basic applications: "App 1" has resources in it, and "App 2" does not have resources.
"App 1" never starts when it is not launched via Visual Studio, while "App 2" does.

Is this a problem with my PC or is it a another thing?

EDIT:

This is the load code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For x = 0 To 8
        vars.bg(x) = New Bitmap(16, 16)
        Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(vars.bg(x))
        gr.DrawImage(vars.img, 0, 0, New RectangleF(x * 16, 0, 16, 16), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    Next
    For x = 0 To 16
        vars.sp(x) = New Bitmap(16, 16)
        Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(vars.sp(x))
        gr.DrawImage(vars.img2, 0, 0, New RectangleF(x * 16, 0, 16, 16), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    Next
    For x = 0 To 1
        vars.bomb(x) = New Bitmap(16, 16)
        Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(vars.bob(x))
        gr.DrawImage(vars.img3, 0, 0, New RectangleF(x * 16, 0, 16, 16), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    Next
    levelload()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: are they in the same solution?

Comment: No, they are in their own solutions. Any app I make that has resources never start. The ones without resources run fine.

Comment: The resources have nothing to do with it.  Is there any error msg at all? Is it a WinForms app?

Comment: There are no error messages. Every time I run an app with resources, the cursor turns into the loading one, and the app never starts. Also if I check Task Manager, then the app's name is shown in the Processes tab. They are WinForms, but this has also happened with a console application.

Comment: If there is code in the form load event [edit] your post to show it.  What kind of resources does this have?

Comment: It has .png files and .txt files. Also, I just noticed when I tested an app without resources, that also never launched!

Comment: We've been having this question asked all week.  Uninstall Avast.